How to check how many delayed job workers in my docker container
I have a running production application which is build with Rails 2.3 LTS and we are running this app as dockerized and in docker swarm mode.
The application uses DelayedJob (version 1.7 which is a too older one but have to use this because of our Rails 2.3 version). Recently when we have added more servers to our application we are noticing that some of the delayed job getting picked up twice and I am just wondering if I can debug it better and if I can see how many worker per docker container is working on servers.
If anyone can let me know the way of checking number of workers inside a docker container and if anything further they have as a debug guidance then it would be a great help.
I haven't tried much other than checking on internet but it seems that my DJ version is too old and there is nothing much that has been available there
